# Disable switching from app to homescreen android wear

Tags: wear-os

I am running a android wear fullscreen app and after a certain time, the watch switches from app screen to the home screen (shows time). Is there any way to shop the switching. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by `switches from app screen to home screen` you mean that the watch goes to sleep / dims the screen.
Well you can prevent this by adding the `android:keepScreenOn` attribute to your layout-file.

For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

Alternatively you can add the flag in your Java-Code as well:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

**Note**: Per default every wear-app will be closed as soon as the screen gets dimmed. A few weaks ago there has been a post on StackOverflow discussing the topic ***"Long Running Apps on Android Wear"***. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699845/long-running-apps-on-android-wear) along with a pretty neat solution.